# JSP - Process a form with a Bean Method with more than one parameter

Tags: java, html, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp

I have this form and want to process it:

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/user" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Text input-->
      <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input name="email" placeholder="email" class="input-xlarge" type="text"
          value="<%=?????????">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Text input-->
      <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input name="password" placeholder="password" class="input-xlarge" type="text"
          value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> 
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type='button' value='Save Changes'
      onclick='document.forms["myForm"].submit();'>
</div>

</div>
```

However, I have a bean method with two parameters and I tried to handle this by using:

```
public void insert(String email, String password) {
    User entry = new User(email, password);
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.makePersistent(entry);
}
```

My question is, how to connect the Bean properly with the form, which uses two parameters?

Comment: You have two unmatched "end div" tags in the middle and at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the bean java file to connect those two? A functional bean file consists of the following three parts:

1. A constructor working as initialization
2. Getters
3. Setters

In the following lines, you will find a plain example concerning a form based on the one you posted above. Remember the old trick of System.out.println's to check everything you are writing is right.

**Bean file , let's call it userData.java**

```
package blabla;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UserData implements Serializable {

private String email;
private String password;

//1.Constructor
public UserData()
{
    email="";
    password="";

}

//2.Getters
public String getEmail(){
return email;
}

public String getPassword(){
return password;
}

//3.Setters - Caution: we use different variables here

public void setEmail(String eml)
{
this.email=eml;
}

public void setPassword(String pswd)
{ 
this.password=pswd;
}   }
```

On the other hand, the .jsp file should resemble like this
**index.jsp**

```
<%--Blablabla headers and stuff, I will only write the things needing to be added--%>
<jsp:useBean id="entry" class="packagePath.UserData" scope="application"/>
<%--For analytic info about the parameters of the jsp call above, check:         http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action--%>
<jsp:setProperty name="entry" property="*"/>
<%--Code to invoke all the setters of the bean--%>
<p><jsp:getProperty name="entry" property="email"/></p>
<p><jsp:getProperty name="entry" property="password"/></p>
<%--The two lines are not obligatory to use; you will need them only if you wan tto print the results on the page--%>
<%-- rest of the code%-->
```

Comment: Be extra careful on the use of scope! If you are using multiple beans on different pages it is forbidden to use the "application" tag. The options you have for scope are page,request,session and application